# Connection and authentication with usb 3g dongle using at-commands

Tags: at-command, access-point-name

I need to authenticate with a usb 3g dongle using at commands.

I can connect using following code:

```
    AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","tim.br"
    ATD*99***1#
```

But I can't request a page, and my interface don't get a IP.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to describe in more details what happens. Which entity is sending those AT commands?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you expect? You get a connection and you are free to exchange data using one of the virtual serial ports. You may get an interface if you use something like DirectIP by SierraWireless, but then you need a driver for that. Still, you get an interface and I'm not sure if you don't need to ask for an IP using DHCP.